# Typescript Class as parameter that extends another class

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm fairly new to Typescript and generics; I must be missing something hopefully trivial.

I'm trying to pass a (generic) class as an argument for a function, but this class extends from another specific class

An oversimplified example would be the following: lets say I have

```
class A { 
    static generate3() { return [new A(),new A(),new A()]; }
}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

I want a method that I would call with any of the classes that inherite from A as parameters and return the result of that static method. Something like

```
f(B) // returns type B[]
```

I figured I can do

```
function f(type: typeof B){
    return type.generate3();
}
```

But this requires me to define the class in advance. I also cannot use typeof B|typeof C cause in real life there is too many clases for this to be practical
I tried

```
function f2<T>(type: typeof T extends A){
    return type.generate3();
}
```

where `T` is supposed to be the class, but it throws the following error: `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

I figured this works

```
function f3(type: typeof A){
    return type.generate3();
}
```

But the return type of f3(B) is still A[] instead of the desired B[]
I tried mixing the two like:

```
function f4<T extends A>(type: typeof A) : T[]{
    return type.generate3() as T[]; // cast it
}
```

But the return type of `f4(B)` is still `A[]`
I don't understand it. Can anyone figure out what I'm I doing wrong?